# php - cannot connect to database. Access denied for user 'UserName'@'%' to database 'table'

Tags: php, mysql, database

I can't seem to access the database to my host's server.  Here's the code that I use to connect to it:

```
$servHost = 'fdb7.biz.nf';
$servPort = '3306';
$servName = '1598934_user';
$servPass = '**********';
$dataTable = 'table';

$connect = @mysql_connect($servHost.':'.$servPort, $servName, $servPass);

$db = @mysql_select_db($dataTable);

if(!$connect || !$db){
    die(mysql_error());
}else{
    echo 'connected';
}
```

When I try to use this I get the error:

```
Access denied for user '1598934_user'@'%' to database 'table'
```

I assume it has something to do with the `%` sign, but I don't know what to replace it with or how. The server is not mine, I'm using biz.nf to host my site.  Any advice appreciated.

Comment: `%` in the access list is a wildcard that means any client host, so I don't think that's the problem. The problem is just that your username doesn't have permission to access that database.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the user **1598934_user** exists in the database. If it does exists, run the following mysql query to grant privileges.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `postsData`.* TO '1598934_user'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

or if you do not want to grant all privileges then use:

```
GRANT <privileges> ON postsData.* TO '1598934_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

or use:

```
GRANT INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE ON postsData.* TO '1598934_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

This should give privileges to the user

Also, if the user does not exists follow the query:

```
CREATE USER '1598934_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

and follow the grant privileges query to give privileges.

Also, if you do not have access to run the above queries, use server name as `localhost` and upload your site contents / files to the host and run from the host.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your Database password, it happens when password is wrong.